# Neatbeans-Java Trabajar con clases

Tags: java

Tengo una clase Futbolista con sus respectivos atributos como goles, posición en la que juega, entre otros y con los métodos para capturar los datos e imprimirlos. Pero necesito hacer un método que devuelva el nombre del Futbolista que tiene más edad.

Tengo otra clase Personal de Equipo donde están los atributos de una persona tipo ID, nombre y apellidos estos atributos los hereda la clase Futbolista.

Luego esta la clase Miembros de Equipo donde esta el main ahí es donde llamo a los métodos en un switch para que la persona pueda elegir en un menú si quiere ingresar un jugador , salir del programa , imprimir la cantidad de jugadores que se han ingresado o imprimir el jugador con más edad. Además tengo la clase entrenador pero por el momento no la uso.

```
package miembrosequipo;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Futbolista extends PersonalEquipo{
    private String posicionJuego;
    private int cantGoles;
    private int edad;

    public Futbolista(){ //constructor vacío
    }
    
    public Futbolista(String posicionJuego, int cantGoles,int edad, int idPersona, String nomPersona, String apePersona, char genPersona, String equipo) {
        super(idPersona, nomPersona, apePersona, genPersona, equipo); 
        this.posicionJuego = posicionJuego;
        this.cantGoles = cantGoles;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    public String getPosicionJuego() {
        return posicionJuego;
    }

    public void setPosicionJuego(String posicionJuego) {
        this.posicionJuego = posicionJuego;
    }

    public int getCantGoles() {
        return cantGoles;
    }

    public void setCantGoles(int cantGoles) {
        this.cantGoles = cantGoles;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    public void capturaDatos(){
        setIdPersona(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ID del futbolista:")));
        setNomPersona(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre del futbolista:"));
        setApePersona(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Apellido del futbolista:"));
        setEdad(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edad del futbolista:")));
        setGenPersona(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Género del futbolista:").charAt(0));
        setEquipo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Equipo del futbolista:"));
        setPosicionJuego(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Posición del futbolista:"));
        setCantGoles(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Goles anotados:")));
    }
    
    public void imprimeFutbolista(){
        System.out.println("Datos del futbolista");
        System.out.println("ID: "+ getIdPersona());
        System.out.println("Nombre: "+ getNomPersona());
        System.out.println("Apellido:" +getApePersona());
        System.out.println("Edad:" +getEdad());
        System.out.println("Género:" +getGenPersona());
        System.out.println("Equipo:" +getEquipo());
        System.out.println("Posición de juego: "+getPosicionJuego());
        System.out.println("Goles anotados: "+getCantGoles());
    }
    
    public String futMayor(){
         int edad = getEdad();
         int edadM = 0;
         String nomFut = getNomPersona();
         String futMayor = "";
             if(edad>edadM){
                 edadM = edad;
                 futMayor = nomFut;
             }
         return futMayor;
    }
```

Comment: te recomiendo poner el codigo que tengas hecho hasta el momento asi podemos ayudarte mejor. Una posible solucion es crear una clase "Equipo" que tenga como atributo un array de jugadores, y ahi podes crear un metodo dentro de la Clase Equipo que evalue ese array comparando la edad de los jugadores. Entonces todo metodo que incluya a varios jugadores puede implementarse en dicha clase nueva

Comment: Al final los jugadores son jugadores porque pertenecen a un equipo, entonces tiene sentido

Comment: Es que no se como hacer para subir el código

Comment: solo copia y pegalo, hay un boton para que la pagina formatee el texto y se muestre como codigo. Entonces seleccionas ese texto que es codigo y le das al boton codigo y se formatea como tal y se ve mejor

Comment: el resto del texto que no es codigo no lo formateas asi obviamente. Igual siempre podes modificar tus preguntas

Comment: ya la logre modificar, muchas gracias

Comment: Tu error (en la concepción del modelo de datos) ha sido intentar poner el método que calcula el de mayor edad en la clase `Futbolista`. La POO funciona como en la vida normal. La clase `Equipo` tendría un conjunto de objetos de la clase `Futbolista` y es en `Equipo` donde debes determinar cuál es el mayor de todos los miembros del equipo.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias. En Equipo también puedo determinar que jugador tiene más goles?